# Apache .htaccess: How to remove question mark from URL if not `?id=(.*)`?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to make .htaccess to **remove question mark from URL if not** `?id=(.*)`**?**

```
# Rewrite for ?id=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]

# It does not work out on this way
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the right rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond !{QUERY_STRING} id
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

**Update**:

```
# Query rewrite exceptions
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !callback=.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Tip: during your testings, use 302 redirections instead of 301, as 301 redirections are stored by browsers. You can finally switch to classic 301 when you are done testing.